# Javascript to iterate through elements not working

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net

I had a JavaScript working until a few minutes ago, now it's not working any more but I didn't change anything.

My JavaScript is:

```
var estadoactual ="";
for (var i=1;i<=document.getElementById("cantidaddepermisos").value;i++) {
var elemento = 'chk_' + i
if (document.getElementById(elemento).checked == 1) {
     estadoactual = estadoactual + elemento + "#" + "Si" + "|"
} 
else {
      estadoactual = estadoactual + elemento + "#" + "No" + "|"
      }
}
alert("Estado actual: " + estadoactual)
```

In my scenario I have several checkboxes (chk_n) and what I want to do is to iterate through them, I know they will have the format chk_ + a number, so I made that "for loop"

This code was working fine, don't know why it stopped working, I'm awake for 3 days working on this project maybe I'm missing something so I need some more people to see and tell if there is something obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it figured out. Thanks a lot for trying to help me and taking your time for this. I will explain what happened in case some one else needs this.

My table was created dinamically, this means my codebehind is creating one with 2 for each "permission" you can select from the DB. Those permissions are loaded in the DB by hand (customer requirement) and you need to put a numer to each one, mines went from 1 to 34 (that was today morning when everything was working) then I added a new profile (99) by a special hidden permission.

This means there are 34 permissions in the DB so the for will loop from 1 to 34, but my checkboxes are named chk_ + "numberofpermission"

This means they are chk_1 to chk_34 AND chk_99 at the end, so when the javascript reached the 34 posittion it was looking for chk_34 wich didn't exist because the name of the checkbox is "chk_99"

Really hard to figure this out but now it's working again, will need to change the way I set this hidden permission to the users to avoid this problem.

Thanks a lot for the time, this community it's really outstanding.

Greetings from Argentina

Answer (score 0):

maybe the trouble would be cache in javascript file.

Try change the source to:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="js/myscript.js?n=1"></script>
```

It's remove cache browser for your javascript file

Comment: But this code was working fine a few hours ago and nothing changed since then, this JS is in the "head" of my aspx page, not in a separate file, I also tried with chrome and FF, both cleaning the cache

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code :

```
for (var i=1;i<=document.getElementById("cantidaddepermisos").value;i++) {
```

You're iterating on your input value that is by default a String. Try to parseInt it :

```
for (var i=1;i<=parseInt(document.getElementById("cantidaddepermisos").value);i++) {
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: I got the same result, seems the problem is in

    "if (document.getElementById(elemento).checked == 1) {"

i got an error in the console about "elemento" not defined or .checked = null